How do I eject an external drive that is indexed by Spotlight?
Similar to this question, I have an external SSD that I use as expanded storage when my MacBook Pro is docked. I would like the contents of that disk to be searchable with Spotlight, so I have indexing enabled. The problem is that most times I try to eject that drive I'm met with the message,

The disk "External" wasn't ejected because one or more programs may be using it.

I believe the culprit is mds and its related processes, but I'm not entirely sure.
Is there a good way to reliably eject an external drive that has Spotlight indexing enabled?

I'd recommend finding the definite cause of the problem first, rather than assuming it's Spotlight.

I have confirmed it is Spotlight.

If you disable Spotlight indexing for the drive by adding it to the privacy list, does it eject promptly? Also, what macOS version? Are you using the latest version compatible with your hardware?

How did you confirm it's Spotlight/mds preventing the eject?

I disabled Spotlight indexing on the drive and observed that the problem stopped until I re-enabled it.

To eject an external drive with Spotlight indexing enabled:

Disable indexing temporarily:
sudo mdutil -i off /Volumes/ExternalDriveName


Eject the drive.

Re-enable indexing:
sudo mdutil -i on /Volumes/ExternalDriveName




How do you expect to re-enable indexing on an unmounted path?

@AndyGriffiths Always amazing that ChatGPT gets such things wrong …

@nohillside https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out is alive and well
